# Change .prev() button to disabled on click of another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I have two buttons and I need one to stay disabled until the other is active. And then I need that same button to become inactive and go back to a previous class if the first button is clicked/toggled again. I only have have access up to jQuery 1.7.2:

```
 <button class="primaryClass" value="primary"></button>
 <button class="linkClass" value="link"></button>
```

Thus far I tried this but it does not seem to be working:

```
$('.linkClass').on('click touchend',function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('linkClass')) {
        $(this).prev('.primaryClass').addClass('disabled');
        e.preventDefault;

    }
    if($(this).hasClass('linkClass-active')) {
        $(this).prev('.primaryClass').removeClass('disabled');

});
```

So basically, the user clicks the button with linkClass the button with primary class becomes enabled because the disabled class is removed. If the user clicks it again, then the primaryClass button again becomes disabled. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: don't get it, you select .linkClass, and check if it has.... .linkClass???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use toggleClass

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$('.linkClass').on('click touchend',function() {

 $(this).prev('.primaryClass').toggleClass('disabled');
    e.preventDefault;
});
```

The part with 'linkClass-active' I don't understand so I left that out.

If you want to also toggle the disabled property use this:

```
 $('.linkClass').on('click touchend',function() {
     var $target =  $(this).prev('.primaryClass');
     $target.toggleClass('disabled');
     $target[0].disabled = !$target[0].disabled;
     e.preventDefault;
});
```

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Yyk2G/

By the way, why are you setting value? its not an input its a button tag.

Comment: There's a lot of bells and whistles going on in the backend... The value is used as a binding logic.

Comment: that makes sense. i usually use the prefix data-, as in data-value. This has the small benefit of being valid html (not that important) and the convenience of being included in jQuerry .data() http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 2):

Your question is fairly vague, please try to make a fiddle. As far as I can tell you should be setting `.prop("disabled", true);` to make the button disabled. If you don't have a css .disabled class, you won't see it, that and you should always use built in functionality.

Comment: Sorry was being lazy with the fiddle. But yes basically toggling the disabled attribute. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding the class you can disable the button using the `disabled` property.  This will prevent clicks on the button from firing any event handlers.

```
 $('.linkClass').on('click touchend',function() {
    var primary = $("button.primaryClass");
    primary.prop("disabled", !primary.is(":disabled"));
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6SNQS/2/

Comment: @isaacweathers Glad I could help.  Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UcUhaDi/1/edit)**:

html

```
   <button class="primaryClass" disabled="disabled" value="primary">Bye</button>
   <button class="linkClass" value="link">Hi</button>
```

js

```
$('.linkClass').on('click touchend',function() {
 $(this).prev().prop('disabled', function(idx, oldAttr) {
        return !oldAttr;
    });    
});
```

jQuery attr() takes a callback. So you can use that to your advantage.

Comment: Yes. Thanks guys. All three appear to be what I need. Now to see which one works in this environment.

Comment: @Alex Shilman "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method." from http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @AlexShilman No problem, attr still works for properties, but you may run into an issue with some browsers if you try to use attr() on a property.